# Сложенные столбчатые графики с Dataframe из padans

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Начал потихоньку изучуать matplotlib в python.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в столбчатом графике задать какие-нибудь(любые) значения оси x, а не индексы в массива.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {'Apple': [1,3,4,3,5],
        'Samsung': [2,4,5,2,4],
        'Xiaomi': [3,2,3,1,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

как мне надо изменить данны входные, и что добавить в matplotlib , чтобы допустим, место цифр (0,1,2,3,4) были например август,сентябрь и т.д.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да по-разному это можно сделать.
Ну, например, вот так:

```
data = {'Apple': [1,3,4,3,5],
        'Samsung': [2,4,5,2,4],
        'Xiaomi': [3,2,3,1,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=['август','сентябрь','октябрь','ноябрь','декабрь'])
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,rot=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]